# What options are available for speeding up video load times on a webpage when video is hosted on IPFS

Tags: javascript, php, video, ffmpeg, playback

I have a site that pulls videos hosted on IPFS (Interplanetary File System), most of the videos load and play fine but if a user doesn't have a strong internet connection or if a larger video, it constantly buffer's and play's choppy.

Since the video isn't hosted on my server i'm not sure what options I have to help speed the load times up. The original video is uploaded to my site though and I pass it to IPFS to upload directly. I don't currently download it to my server first to speed up the uploading process, or so the user doesn't need to wait for a double upload.

I know youTube has a compression algorithm and does something with chopping up the video into chunks or something but i'm not sure exactly how that works. Im not very experienced with video codec and encoding. Ive heard good things about FFmpeg but not sure if that would help my current situation.

Any ideas or tools I should look into that may help me out would be appreciated. For larger videos I could download to my server first if theres a compression mechanism or something I could apply first to help the overall load times of the site although not ideal for the user uploading.

Im using videoJS for my video player with preload set to auto if that helps at all.

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls  class="video-js video" poster="{Image URL}" "preload="auto">
    <source src="{IPFS URL}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Options im currently using

Load the video after the DOM has loaded to not slow down page loads

Preload the video

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="{IPFS URL}" as="video" crossorigin>
```

Although I don't think that does much.

Other than that I don't know what else I can do. Im good with PHP and or Javascript to handle this task if theres something I should look into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use the PHP-FFmpeg library to encode and edit video files. Basically if a user uploads a large file or a format other than the accepted formats it will encode the video to a h.264 mp4 file. It reduces the filesize substantially and offers a bunch of other cool options for video editing.

```
https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg
```